# Real bad accuracy of training test on neural network on keras

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I'm doing a Neural Network for the "Default of credit card clients" from http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/default+of+credit+card+clients.

But the accuracy of my models is pretty bad, worse than if I predicted all zeros. I already did some research on it and did oversample to correct the classes, and change the optimizer, because adam was not increasing the accuracy.

What else could I do?

```
import pandas 
import numpy

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import keras
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE


seed = 8
numpy.random.seed(seed)


base = pandas.read_csv('base_nao_trabalhada.csv')


train, test = train_test_split(base, test_size = 0.2)




train=train.values
test=test.values

X_train = train[:,1:23]
Y_train = train[:,24]
X_test =  test[:,1:23]
Y_test = test[:,24]

sm = SMOTE(kind='regular')

X_resampled, Y_resampled = sm.fit_sample(X_train, Y_train)



# Model Creation
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(40, input_dim=22, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
#activation='relu'

opt = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.000001)

# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt , metrics=['accuracy'])
#loss=binary_crossentropy
#optimizer='adam'


# creating .fit
model.fit(X_resampled, Y_resampled, nb_epoch=10000, batch_size=30)




# evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)
print ()
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

Comment: How do I get that `base_nao_trabalhada.csv` file? I've only downloaded a `default credit card clients.xls` file.

Comment: you will have a massive class imbalance why would you use accuracy? I would be using AUC to rank the decisions. Also, the accuracy would be higher if you have a huge class imbalance - see the scenario of 99% class 0 and 1% class 1 - I can predict all 0's and still get a accuracy of 99%. Look for other metrics. But cool data set.

Comment: Try to change normal init to he_init